# Why does my awk command adds the string to the beginning instead of appending at last

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to put a char at the end of each line in a file:

```
a
aa
aaa
aah
aahed
aahing
aahs
aal
aalii
aaliis
```

using sed/awk:

```
awk '{print  $0 "A"}' words_alpha.txt > words_alpha_hyp.txt
sed -i 's/$/A/' words_alpha.txt > words_alpha_hyp.txt
```

I got always instead the char 'a' a prefix:

```
 A
 A
 Aa
 Ah
 Ahed
 Ahing
 Ahs
 Al
 Alii
 Aliis
 Als
 Am
 Ani
 Ardvark
 Ardvarks
```

Interestingly if I try to '\n' before the char 'a':

```
awk '{print $0 "\n a"}' words_alpha.txt > words_alpha_hyp.txt

a
 a
aa
 a
aaa
 a
aah
 a
aahed
 a
aahing
 a
aahs
 a
aal
 a
```

I does what it supposed to do... I don't understand it...

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file most likely has DOS CRLF line terminators i.e. instead of `\n` being a `\r\n`. Modify your record separator to handle those lines, needs GNU `awk` for having to use a multi character record separator

```
awk -v RS="\r\n" '{ $0 = $0 "a" }1' file
```

Or make the obvious choice of converting the file to *nix line endings `\n` by doing `dos2unix file` and run your original command again.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for multi-char RS.

Comment: Thanks. @EdMorton I do I agree the answer was in the post you cite but it could not be found with my search